# Cleaning up Main to Dev changesets

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge

My Main branch seems to have change sets that my Dev branch does not have, but they are older. **How should/can I clean up the changes sets?**

The following is trying to merge Main into Dev and says there are changes. My understanding is that if Main and Dev match I should not see change sets during this merge anymore.

If I merge from Dev to Main I see no change sets.

Should I merge these even though newer change sets have already been applied? Example changes were made and merge into Main on 4/25.

Will this overwrite current code or will it really just update histories?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [tf merge command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/merge-command) with `/discard` option.

> **/discard** Does not perform the merge operation, but updates the merge
>   history to track that the merge occurred. This discards a changeset
>   from being used for a particular merge.

Sample command：

```
tf merge $/Project/SourceBranch $/Project/TargetBranch /discard /recursive /version:C56693~C56693
```

It discards changeset 56693. The version is a from ~ to, so you can discard multiple changesets at once. When the command has finished, you still need to **check in the merge**.